# Why does nothing write to my file?

Tags: java, file, output, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have a program that I am working on and I have an issue with writing a string into my file. The file is created, but the string value that should be written into it ultimately does not get written. There are no syntax errors according to Eclipse, so I suppose it's a semantical error.

```
public boolean createFile()
{
    try
    {
        f = new File("house.txt");
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            f.createNewFile();
            exists = true;
        }
        else 
            exists = false;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return exists;
}
```

That's the method that creates the file.
This next one is the method that actually writes to the file, which is successfully created. The action is derived from a JButton that, when pressed, should perform this:

```
if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("CONFIRM"))
    {
        attribute = txt.getText();
        try
        {
            createFile();
            fWriter = new FileWriter(f);
            String content = attribute;         
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            output.write(content);
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Is this empty? :  attribute = txt.getText();

Comment: I strongly suspect you're getting an exception, which should be printed out to the console. (This is *not* good exception handling, btw.) Have a look there. Note that you're currently trying to create two `FileWriter` objects for the same file... that's not likely to work.

Comment: call flush method after write

Comment: @user503413: No need given the close call - although that should be in a finally block, or using try-with-resources.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to use `File.createNewFile()` at all. Creating the `FileWriter` will create the file if necessary.

Comment: @Semrano: The attribute variable doesn't seem to be empty. Just to make sure, I tried replacing String contents with a static value of "abc," but it still did not write.

Comment: @user3324895: When did I say you didn't need to call close? I said you didn't need to call *flush* if you're calling close.

Comment: @JonSkeet My apologizes, I confused the numbers on the end of my handle..

Comment: In @user2864740's defense: I thought you said the same thing, JonSkeet.

Comment: you might need a stringReader ;  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(content));

Comment: @Sembrano: No, that's absolutely *not* required.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect you're getting exceptions logged - you should improve your exception handling anyway, but if you're *going* to log exceptions, you really need to look in the logs when things don't work!

This is almost certainly the problem:

```
fWriter = new FileWriter(f);
String content = attribute;         
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
```

You're creating two `FileWriter`s for the same file. The first one's existence will stop the second one from being created properly.

However, there are plenty of other points you should note:

- `FileWriter` always uses the platform default encoding. I far prefer to explicitly specify an encoding, usually UTF-8.
- Creating a new `FileWriter` (or `FileOutputStream`) already creates the file if it doesn't exist, so your `createFile` method is pointless (unless you really need to check whether or not the file previously exists)
- You should always close your stream resources in a `finally` block or using a try-with-resources statement in Java 7.

Libraries can make this sort of thing *much* simpler though. I would use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) rewrite your whole code as:

```
if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("CONFIRM")) {
    Files.write(txt.getText(), new File("house.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Declare that your method can throw `IOException`, or catch it if you *really* want to handle it in the method.

If you really want to do it manually:

```
if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("CONFIRM")) {
  try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
      new FileOutputStream("house.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    writer.write(txt.getText());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if `attribute = txt.getText();` is empty it wont write anything to your file.

Otherwise do.

```
if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("CONFIRM"))
    {
        attribute = txt.getText();
        try
        {
            createFile();
            fWriter = new FileWriter(f);
            String content = attribute;         
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            output.write(content);
            output.flush();
            output.close();


        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

or else add a stringReader :  `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(content));`

Comment: There is absolutely *no* need to start using a `StringReader` here - what benefit do you think that would have? And you've propagated the original problem, which is creating two `FileWriter`s. The OP has stated that the problem persists even if `txt.getText()` is changed to "abc", so this definitely isn't the issue.

Comment: Yeh, but I wrote answer before that. So you found the real problem.

Comment: Or before I saw the replies :-)

Answer (score 1):

`txt.getText();` is probably empty.

The JavaDoc also warns of this, though, about createNewFile:

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist.

Comment: He said in a comment that he tried a manually created string and it still didn't write.

Comment: I also just commented out the method call for createFile() which has .createNewFile() in it, considering the advice of someone above who suggested that FileWriter would essentially create the file anyways. Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Enter this code. It will help you to copy one file to another and will copy only the palindromes which are there in your file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Reader {
    public static String reverse(String s)
    {
        String str= new String(""); 
        for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            str+=s.charAt(i);
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //File m=new File("C:\\bg/newfile.txt");
        int count=0;
        FileReader f=new FileReader("C:\\bg/newfile.txt");
        FileWriter fa=new FileWriter("C:\\bg/newfile1.txt");
        BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(f);
        BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(fa);
        String line=bf.readLine();
        //String li=br.newLine();
        while(line!=null)
        {
            String[] sa=line.split(" ");
            for(String a:sa)
            {
                if(a.equals(reverse(a)))
                {
                    System.out.println(a);
                    br.write(a);
                    br.newLine();
                    count++;
                }
                //System.out.println(count+""+a);
            }
            //br.newLine();
            line=bf.readLine();
        }
        bf.close();
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is this:

```
    try {       
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("house.txt")));
        output.write(txt.getText());
        output.close();

    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If `house.txt` does not exist then it will be created. If `txt.getText()` returns a string it will be written to `house.txt`.

I would also suggest using a try-with-resources statement if possible which will close your stream for you after the try block exits.

```
    try (BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("house.txt")))){
        output.write(txt.getText());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure this should work, along with several other solutions that have been posted. I'm starting to think it's a problem with my ActionListener. Essentially, a Jbutton add, when clicked will open up a window with a JComboBox, upon selecting an option form that JComboBox a new frame will open with a textfield and a "CONFIRM" button. The ActionListener for both of these buttons is in the same method. Could that have anything to do with the issue?

Comment: Sorry I have never used Swing so I can't help you much with that, I would check to see if this code is being executed and that txt.getText() does return a string which is not empty.

Comment: The code executes fine, and does not crash at any instance, so the problem isn't syntactical. But thank you.